# Google calendar api v3 order by created time in PHP or Javascript

Tags: sorting, google-calendar-api

How can I order my events in google calendar from the latest to oldest. I've read some of the documentation but, It doesn't seem to work.

used parameters:

```
orderby=created
orderby=updated
orderby=start
orderby=starttime
sortorder=ascending
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use singleEvents=True and orderBy=startTime

As far as I know you can't use sortOrder in v3.

To order by start time, single events must be true as mentioned here:
https://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#api_params

Good luck!